# Prove the following inequality (probably) using derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In chapter where we use derivatives for determining local minima/maxima there is this inequality where I really do not know where to start.

Prove:

$$ \frac{1}{2^{p-1}} \leq x^p +(1-x)^p \leq 1  $$ for $$ x \in [{0,1}], \ p > 1 $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: setting $$f(x)=x^p+(1-x)^{p}$$ then we get $$f'(x)=px^{p-1}-p(1-x)^{p-1}$$ and $$f'(x)=0$$ if $x=\frac{1}{2}$. For the second derivative $$f''(x)=p(p-1)x^{p-2}+p(p-1)(1-x)^{p-2}$$ we get a minimum at $x=1/2$ and we have $$f(x)\geq 1/2^{p-1}$$ and the right-hand side $$x^p+(1-x)^p\le 1$$ is trivial

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=x^p+(1-x)^p$.
$$f'(x)=p\left(x^{p-1}-(1-x)^{p-1}\right)=0$$
$$\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right)^{p-1}=\left(\frac1x-1\right)^{p-1}=1$$
As $\frac1x-1\ge0$, $x=\frac12$. Therefore extrema of $f(x)\in\{f(0),f(\frac12),f(1)\}=\{\frac1{2^{p-1}},1\}$.
$$\therefore \frac1{2^{p-1}}\le x^p+(1-x)^p\le 1$$